# Inject TypeORM DataSource using tsyringe in Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, typeorm, tsyringe

I am trying to inject `TypeORM` data source into repository class using `tsyringe` DI library, `node` + `express`, like this:

```
const PostgresDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "postgres",
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
});

container.register("DataSource", {
  useValue: PostgresDataSource,
});

@AutoInjectable()
export class TypeormExampleRepository implements ExampleRepository {
  private readonly repository: Repository<Entity>;

  constructor(@inject("DataSource") private readonly dataSource: DataSource) {
    this.repository = PostgresDataSource.getRepository(Entity);
  }

  ...
}
```

But I constantly get `Attempted to resolve unregistered dependency token: "DataSource"` error message. How this dependency injection should be executed?